# Snakemake: github module using python module in repo

Tags: snakemake

I want to use a snakemake workflow available on github as a module in my new workflow. I define it like this:

```
module distiller:
    snakefile:
        github("open2c/distiller-sm", path="workflow/Snakefile", branch="master")
        # "distiller-sm-master/workflow/Snakefile"
    config:
        config
use rule * from distiller as distiller_*
```

The distiller module uses local .py files available in the GitHub repo like this:

```
from .scripts.common import organize_fastqs, needs_downloading
```

This is where I get a problem: in my new workflow I get this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError in file https://raw.githubusercontent.com/open2c/distiller-sm/master/workflow/Snakefile, line 4:
No module named 'snakemake.scripts'
```

Is there a way to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Luckily, I can modify the workflow that I am using as a module, and the solution is to turn the scripts.py file into a rulefile and use the snakemake `include: file.smk` syntax instead of python import. Then snakemake picks up this dependency!

So for this situation it solves the problem. But not for other uses of a separate python files, for example, when one calls a python script within a shell: execution block within a rule.

Comment: A way to get the python script into shell is to use workflow.source_path in the params section. Feels ugly but at least it works, e.g.:


```
…
    params:
        DupMasker_bed9=workflow.source_path("../scripts/DupMasker_bed9.py"),
    shell:
        """
        python {params.DupMasker_bed9} …
        ""”
```